# i cant see the changes even reloadable is true in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, reloadable

hi I'm using eclipse and I'm trying out a few things with servlets.

Why in eclipse when i run a file after changes, i can't see the changes even though i set re loadable to true?
i have a class that extends HttpServlet and in the doGet method I'm printing out just "Hello World!" and when I'm doing some changes i try to rerun it and everything stays like it was the first time.
I'm using Apache tomcat 7.

is there a way to fix it?

```
<Context reloadable="true"> 
</Context>
```

Comment: Make sure you're restarting the Tomcat after every change you do. Also, check if the Build Automatically option is enabled on your Eclipse.

Comment: where is the build automatically option? @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: and you r sure i have to restart tomcat?? so whats the point of reloadable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to build from scratch.
Do the following:
1. Restart your server(tomcat)
2.Using eclipse Menu go to Project=>clean this will clean previous output

Comment: no it dose not work for me.... it save my changes only when im restarting eclipse. why?